# Android: How to add a textfiled and a check box automatically after click a button/check box

Tags: android, checkbox, textfield

I am trying to make a small app to manage daily money.

And here is my problems:

1. I want after I check a checkbox, generate 1 new text field and 1 new checkbox (SOLVED)
2. How can I manage the id of new checkbox and textfield ?

This is my prototype of the app: (Im using Fluidui)
https://www.fluidui.com/editor/live/preview/p_mw30OzhD3TN5q8T6yGWLHSpTm3b7n6gT.1396421502773

Comment: :after enabling check box.. Try to add dynamically views...this link would help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588059/adding-multiple-layout-dynamically-android

Comment: I try to follow their code but i have error at LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext)..
Do you mind write me a example of my problem..Im new to android so an example will be so helpfull

Comment: instead of mContext give getApplicationContext()

Comment: Hope this link would helps you.. http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/creating-dynamic-views-in-android/<br>
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html

Comment: I try that already..i wont get me error..but nothing happen when i click the button :"<

Comment: can you try with the below links which i have mentioned Roux

Comment: yes..my problem now is when i use getApplicationContext..the new textfiel and new check box..they are blur..i want they to look normal..u can take a look at my prototype..u will understand what im trying to do :"<

Comment: https://www.fluidui.com/editor/live/preview/p_mw30OzhD3TN5q8T6yGWLHSpTm3b7n6gT.1396421502773
Here..Just take a look..Thank you

Comment: have u tried this.. instead of getApplicationContext() please mention Classname.this

Comment: i dont quite get it..what do u mean Classname.this ?..sorry if this is a stupid question :"<

Comment: Do u have solution for my second problem ?

Comment: Try this link for second solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746313/get-id-for-views-that-are-added-dynamically.. Upvote it sparrow pls for answer

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow..what do u mean upvote ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923587/how-to-get-data-from-each-dynamically-created-edittext-in-android .. hope this will help you to clear second prob